# Nested SELECT in mysqli with prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, nested

Im trying to list out a table to show user permission in a PHP-application.
Im trying to do it with MySQLi, but need some help on the way.

I have theese tables:

```
tblUsers(userID PK, username)
tblUsersRoles (roleID PK, roleName)
tblUsersPermission (permissionID PK, permissionName)
tblUsersUserRole (userID FK, roleID FK)
tblUsersRolesPermissions (roleID FK, permissionID FK)
```

I want to show a table like this for each user:

```
-------------------------------------
- RoleName     - PermissionName     -
-------------------------------------
- Admin        - Edit profile       -
-              - Edit permissions   -
-              - Create invoice     -
-------------------------------------
- UserAdmin    - Add user           -
-              - Edit user          -
-              - Delete user        -
-------------------------------------
```

How is this possible? I have tried with nested prepared statements, but only get errors that I dont know enogh to fix myself. Can anybody help?

After what I have read it has somthing to do about store_result(), but I cant seem to get hold of it...

My code so far is this:

```
    <table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>RoleName</th>
        <th>PermissionName</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
        //Get roles where the user is a member from tblUsersUserRoles
        $userID = $_SESSION['userID'];
        $table = DBPREFIX.'tblUsersUserRoles UR, '.DBPREFIX.'tblUsersRoles R';
        $query = "SELECT UR.roleID, R.roleName FROM $table WHERE R.roleID = UR.roleID AND UR.userID=? ORDER BY UR.roleID";
        $statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);
        $statement->bind_param('i', $userID);
        $statement->execute();
        $statement->bind_result($roleID, $roleName);

        while($statement->fetch()) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$roleName.'</td>';
            echo '<td></td>';
            echo '</tr>';


            //Get permissions for this role
            $table2 = DBPREFIX.'tblUsersPermissions P, '.DBPREFIX.'tblUsersRolesPermissions RP';
            $query2 = "SELECT P.permissionName FROM $table2 WHERE P.permissionID = RP.permissionID AND RP.roleID=? ORDER BY P.permissionGroup";
            $statement2 = $mysqli->prepare($query2);
            $statement2->bind_param('i', $roleID);
            $statement2->execute();
            $statement2->bind_result($permissionName);

            while($statement2->fetch()) {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td></td>';
                echo '<td>'.$permissionName.'</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
            $statement2->close();
        }   
        $statement->close();

    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: You should learn to use ANSI JOIN syntax instead of implicit joins.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: I'm getting "prepare() failed: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now".

Comment: I think calling `$statement->store_result();` after `$statement->execute();` will fix that.

Comment: When I add $statement->store_result(); after $statement->execute(); I only get this error: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object. If I try to remove the $statement->bind_result($roleID, $roleName); I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using nested queries, use one query with a `JOIN` between the tables.

```
$query = "SELECT UR.roleID, R.roleName, P.permissions
          FROM ".DBPREFIX."tblUsersUserRoles UR
          JOIN ".DBPREFIX."tblUsersRoles R ON R.roleID = UR.roleID
          LEFT JOIN ".DBPREFIX."tblUsersRolesPermissions RP ON RP.roleID = R.roleID
          LEFT JOIN ".DBPREFIX."blUsersPermissions P ON P.permissionID = RP.permissionID
          WHERE UR.userID = ?
          ORDER BY UR.roleID, P.permissionGroup";
    $statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);
    $statement->bind_param('i', $userID);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->bind_result($roleID, $roleName, $permissionName);
```

Then when you're processing the results, you display the role name row whenever it changes.

```
$lastRoleID = null;

while ($statement->fetch()) {
    if ($roleID != $lastRoleID) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$roleName.'</td>';
        echo '<td></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        $lastRoleID = $roleID;
    }
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td></td>';
    echo '<td>'.$permissionName.'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me. I have read up on join and will use it in the future :-)